# How to implement Logout in a JWT based Single Sign On authentication architecture?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, jwt, openid-connect

I'm trying to understand how to implement the logout feature in a Single Sign On architecture using Json Web Tokens.

Let's say we have :

- `example1.com`
- `example2.com`
- `authserver.com`

When the user has to authenticate on `example1.com`, he is redirected to `authserver.com` which validates the user credentials, creates a signed JWT token and redirects the user back to `example1.com` with this token. `example1.com` will then set a cookie (or a LocalStorage key) and the user will be authenticated on `example1.com`, for as long as the token is not expired. No more call to `authserver.com` is required to identify the user.

The user then goes to `example2.com`, which participates in the SSO architecture. The user needs to be authenticated there too, so `example2.com` also redirects the user to `authserver.com` which recognizes the user (using a cookie it has set the first time), creates a new JWT token and automatically redirects the user back to `example2.com`. `example2.com` will then set a cookie (or a LocalStorage key) and the user will be authenticated on `example2.com`, for as long as the token is not expired. No more call to `authserver.com` is required to identify the user.

*Now, how can a "logout" feature be implemented?*

If the user logs out on `example1.com`, the JWT token on `example1.com` is deleted and the user shouldn't be authenticated there anymore. But as soon as he tried to reach a protected area, `example1.com` will redirect him to `authserver.com`, the user will be recognized and automatically logged in again... Even if he just logged out!

**Quetion 1)** So I guess that when the user logs out on `example1.com`, a call to `authserver.com` must be done *to remove the cookie set by `authserver.com`* so the user won't be logged in automatically anymore?

**Quetion 2)** If so, what about `example2.com`? Should the user still be authenticated there? If not, what is the suggested flow so `example2.com` knows that the JWT token it has for the user isn't valid anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RPLogout is one spec (there are other specs for different strategies) to sign out of the authserver as well. It defines an `end_session_endpoint` that your example1.com would redirect to; note that the authserver signs the user out and can redirect back to the RP's `post_logout_redirect_uri`.

2) I think that depends on what you want it to do. You may not want to kill the example2.com session, in which case example2.com would carry on. The JWT for example2.com is still valid. If you want to logout of all your clients, it's a bit more complicated but possible. In my project, logging out of the one client and the authserver was what we wanted.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! But I'm not sure why the user should be redirected to the OP when he logs out... I can't think of any real case where this has occured to me. When I click a "logout" link, I want to be logged out directly, not redirected to another site to confirm the action! Also, even if the user is redirected to the OP and confirms he wants to log out, he may still be authenticated on another site, `example2.com` for exemple. So the result is a little bit weird, in my opinion. This flow makes sense if there is a way for  `example2.com` to know its token isn't valid anymore, though.

Comment: I wonder if there could be a problem with the backend server, `example1.com`, to call `end_session_endpoint` on the OP *by itself*, by passing the JWT token to clear the session for... So without the need for the user to be redirected there. Am I missing something important?

Comment: One OP implementation, IdentityServer3 (https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/endSession.html) redirects only to redirect you back to the client immediately if you provide both the JTW and the post_logout_redirect_uri. If everything is ok, you never even see the OP. There are other specs to do similar things (in fact IdentityServer3 just implemented another one yesterday: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-logout-1_0.html) but the trick is that the browser cookie on the OP needs to be cleared...I can't think of how you'd do this without being on the OP somehow)

Comment: I guess a backend call to the OP could invalidate the "session" associated to the user cookie, so this cookie isn't valid anymore without being deleted. But I agree that if it's a quick redirect/redirect back, it's ok. I asked because the OpenID specs you posted state : `At the logout endpoint, the OP SHOULD ask the End-User whether he wants to log out of the OP as well. If the End-User says "yes", then the OP MUST log out the End-User.`. But it's a *should* and not a *must*, so I guess an automatic logout + instant redirection is ok too...

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively you could also implement a cross domain SSO without openid, only using JWT on client side, like google web apps.

The advantage is that you do not need to redirect the user to the server to know if the user is logged in. Logout and JWT changes could be automatically synchronized between tabs.

After Authserver.com returns the JWT to example1, store it in localStorage, but use  an intermediate domain sso.example.com through an iframe. Include this iframe in example1 and example2 (pointing to sso.example.com). The iframe will read JWT and send a message to the page containing the token.

When the user logs out or change the active user, the iframe also could send a message to parent, so you can sync all your sites (if you want)

No problem with CORS because sso.example.com have access to its localStorage. And communication between iframes is allowed if  origin and destination are recognized (see http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage)

To simplify development, we have released recently a **cross domain SSO with JWT at https://github.com/Aralink/ssojwt**

Summarizing your questions as this architecture
1) Clean the JWT in localStorage and send a javascript event
2) Listen the event and decides what to do

Comment: browsers seems begin to block third party cookies/stop tracking across domain, the server loaded in an iframe will not have access to that server's cookie and localStorage. So this approach won't work anymore. link: https://www.theverge.com/2020/1/14/21064698/google-third-party-cookies-chrome-two-years-privacy-safari-firefox